# Checking if a ApexClass,ApexPage or ApexTrigger is Managed or Not?

Tags: apex, soql, managed-package

Is there any way to Query and see If a class in the Org is Managed or not ?

```
SELECT ApiVersion,Body,BodyCrc,CreatedById,CreatedDate,Id,IsValid,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,LengthWithoutComments,Name,NamespacePrefix,Status,SystemModstamp FROM ApexClass
```

Is there any specific attribute for a class/trigger/VFPage sObjects to find if its Managed or not ?

I just want to query for Managed classes in the org and display(say in a table)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT Body,BodyCrc,LengthWithoutComments,Name,NamespacePrefix 
FROM ApexClass
WHERE NamespacePrefix != null
```

is a good start. Managed code will be hidden (examine the `Body, BodyCrc and LengthWithoutComments` columns). But the columns don't filter properly (they display as "-1" for example but `WHERE LengthWithoutComments < 0` gives me no results.

So perhaps you'll have to filter them out from your result set manually.

VF pages' code is visible though (but VF components aren't). But `SELECT Markup,Name,NamespacePrefix FROM ApexPage` will give you HUGE results so maybe omit the `Markup` column.

Comment: Tried various possible way to filter . No luck. Is it a bug that it returns me records with values -1 even after i put this filter condition ? `(WHERE LengthWithoutComments > 0)` ? or is there any other way to filter it properly other than looping through results and then filtering?

Comment: I **think** check by prefix is enough as it should be applicable to managed packages only: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_namespace_prefix.htm Are you getting false positives anywhere? (managed class/trigger but the Length... > 0)?